# PHP preg_replace with logic?

Tags: php, regex, string

What if I want to multiply all numbers by 2? Can this be done with regex replace? Note the `$1*2` part that obviously doesn't work. How would I do this?

```
$foo = "soup 12 cake 23 pants";
$bar = preg_replace('~(\d+)~', $1*2, $foo);
```

Comment: Variable names can't be numbers.

Comment: You could use preg_replace_callback

Comment: @PLB Yea, that's cute. Read the question.

Comment: @knittl `preg_replace_callback` is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
preg_replace_callback('~(\d%)~', function($match) { return $match[1]*2; }, $foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

try using the preg_replace_callback(...) function

```
<?php

function mulBy2($match) {
    return $match[1] * 2;
}

$foo = "soup 12 cake 23 pants";
$bar = preg_replace_callback('~(\d+)~', "mulBy2", $foo);

echo $bar;

?>
```